OData response empty when not including $top parameter
I've inherited an undocumented .NET Framework 4.6.1 codebase written in C#, querying an Influx data store and implemented using OData. Queries hitting the API will commonly include $orderby and $filter parameters, which appear to work as expected but only when $top is also present. If $top is omitted, results are empty.
Ordering of the result set is done in application code using LINQ, via OrderBy() and OrderByDescending() on an IQueryable. In the same section of code where those expressions are used, there is a Take() which appears to apply the $top logic by reading query options. However, I have debugged and when the $top parameter is omitted the code does avoid the Take() call on the IQueryable, which as far as I can tell should work fine.
Yet, as stated, when $top is omitted no results are returned from the query. I'm relatively new to OData and the codebase seems a bit squirrelly, but I haven't seen anything that's an obvious smoking gun. Thank you for any help.
Tried including various combinations of filter settings and query parameters. Unfortunately, in all cases omitting $top results in no data.

Could you please provide a Code sample where we can see how your Ordering logic is implemented? My first guess would be: When using ordering and skip/take the order of the statements is important. When you use e.g.:  Skip and Take first and then OrderBy, the results can be different than the other way around, especially when you materialize your IQueryable with ToList() or ToArray().

@Jörg There's not really anything to see in that regard--when the $top query-string parameter is absent there is no Skip() or Take(), and that's when the result set is erroneously empty.

Is this also happening when you just use the pure OData Query without adding extra OrderBy() custom code? It would still help to see some code. Otherwise its just guessing.

It is also happening then, yes. Thank you.

Do you have an example for an odata query where this is happening?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
